# Database design - normalize or denormalize

Tags: database-design

I have a table called Company in our ERP database. We are creating a reporting database for our ERP database and denormalizing the tables for faster querying. So the Company table has both customer records as well as vendor records. I have been thinking to split this table into two tables Customer and Vendor, but was wondering if you guys have any thoughts on the pros and cons.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're creating a database for your ERP database? Can you edit your question and expand on that a little?

Answer (score 0):

The question of whether or not to normalize/denormalize data is very specific to your data and your customer's needs.

Some things I would consider:

1. For reporting, which model is easier to write reports against? Is it easier to get all the data in one shot? Then denormalize. Do you find yourself jumping through hoops in the reporting logic with a denormalized model? Then normalize.
2. I would consider the size of the entities involved. If you have 10 companies, but each company has 10,000 vendors, then maybe it's a bad idea to denormalize company+vendor for a report about companies. Why fetch huge sets of data when all you need is a few company fields? So if any entity has quite a few records, I would consider normalizing for speed.
3. Which is easier to update? Maybe this isn't an issue, but if you aren't writing a view or sproc to denormalize, one approach will be easier to support with writes/updates than the other.

From my experience, if the tables are designed well and not overly normalized (having 30 tables when really something like 10 would do fine), then I prefer to report off of normalized data.